# Uploading image onto server

Tags: android, upload

```
public class Upload {

ProgressDialog dialog = null;
int serverResponseCode = 0;
String uploadFilePath = null;
String uploadFileName = null;
String msg = null;
String upLoadServerUri = " http://192.168.1.179/index.php";
protected MainActivity context;

public Upload(MainActivity context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {


    String fileName = sourceFileUri;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

        context.dialog.dismiss();



        return 0;

    } else {
        try {

            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

            // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                    + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // create a buffer of  maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {

                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                    + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            if (serverResponseCode == 200) {


                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                String line;
                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(line);
                    response.append('\r');
                }
                rd.close();
                context.q_no.setText(response);

                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();











                context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        String msg = "yes";

                        //context.messageText.setText(msg);
                        Toast.makeText(context, "File Upload Complete.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

            }
     } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

     Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            context.dialog.dismiss();
            e.printStackTrace();


            Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "
                    + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        context.dialog.dismiss();
        return serverResponseCode;

     }
  }
}
```

i tried above code to capture image and upload onto php server.it works fine.when i upload image server return a value.but when i try this code i get following exception after image is uploaded onto the server and the server response.

```
  07-27 10:50:55.303: W/System.err(4649):     android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correctly running `upload` on a separate thread (AsyncTask?) -- good. However, anytime you interact with the UI (`.dialog.dismiss()`, `.setText(...)`, etc), you will need to run this on the UI thread.

Answer (score 2):

it because you are trying to update the view. may be dialog.dissmiss()  is causing it. because you have created it in Main thread i think. and you are dismiss it from background thread. background thread can't update view. so it may be the problem.

Comment: try to run it on MainUI thread. as you have already done in your code for showing toast.

Comment: and if you have used AsyncTask then you can dismiss dialog from onPost execute method.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button b,b1;
TextView messageText;
String upLoadServerUri = null;
 private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
 private String selectedImagePath;
 int serverResponseCode = 0;
    ProgressDialog dialog = null;
 //   String selectedPath = "/mnt/sdcard/";
// private ImageView img;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  //  img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    messageText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    upLoadServerUri = "http://urlocation/picture_upload.php";
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent();
             intent.setType("image/*");
             intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
             startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
        }
    });
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
                                }
                            });                      
                         uploadFile(selectedImagePath);
                    }
                  }).start();        
            }
        });
}
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
               // img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
                //uploadFile(selectedImagePath);
            }
        }
    }
public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {
        String fileName = sourceFileUri;
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
          DataOutputStream dos = null;  
          String lineEnd = "\r\n";
          String twoHyphens = "--";
          String boundary = "*****";
          int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
          byte[] buffer;
          int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
          File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 
            if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
            dialog.dismiss(); 
            Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"+selectedImagePath);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {
                       messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"+selectedImagePath);
                   }
               }); 
            return 0;
            }
          else
          {
          try { 
          // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                   FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                   URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
            // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                   conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
                   conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                   conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                   conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                   conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                   conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 
               dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
               dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                                         + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

               // create a buffer of  maximum size
               bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

               bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
               buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

               // read file and write it into form...
               bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

               while (bytesRead > 0) {

                 dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                 bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                 bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                 bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                }

               // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

               // Responses from the server (code and message)
               serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
               String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

               Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " 
                       + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

               if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                          +"http://urlocation/picture_upload.php";

                            messageText.setText(msg);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File Upload Complete.", 
                                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });                
               }    

               //close the streams //
               fileInputStream.close();
               dos.flush();
               dos.close();

          } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

              dialog.dismiss();  
              ex.printStackTrace();

              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              });

              Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
          } catch (Exception e) {

              dialog.dismiss();  
              e.printStackTrace();

              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", 
                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              });
              Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : " 
                                               + e.getMessage(), e);  
          }
          dialog.dismiss();       
          return serverResponseCode; 

       } // End else block 
     } 

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
}
```